# Updating shopping cart quantity

Tags: php

I have a shopping cart in PHP which works fine, but I still can't update quantity of selected product.

This is how I show user what is in his shopping cart.

```
    $cart = Cart::getCart();
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="editCart" />
    foreach ($cart as $c) { 
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $c['idProduct']; ?>">
     <input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$c['idProduct']];?>"
    }
    <button type="submit" title="Update cart" class="button btn-continue pull-right">
     <span>
      <span>Update shopping cart</span>
     </span>
    </button>
```

Here is my function updateCart()

```
public static function updateCart($data) {
        $id = $data['id']; //id product
        $quantity = $data['qty']; //qty

        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])) {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$id] += $quantity;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $quantity;
        }   
    }
```

When I call this function via post, nothing happens.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: have you any error in your logs?

Comment: Is it because $quantity is a string and you're adding it to an int? Try `$_SESSION['cart'][$id] += intval($quantity);`

Comment: well you did not paste code where you actually pass data from `POST` and use `updateCart()`. PS. your first code looks like you mix php with html without closing php tags?

Comment: I am closing tags separately for each php code because of HTML syntax higlighting. When I var_dump $id and $quantity everytime I get only id and quantity of last product in shopping cart.